# How to have a NumPy array only have integer values?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I am writing a program to find Isis rectangles based on a user input of n. The goal of the program is to run through the equation based on the input and output an array of dimensions for a rectangle where area == perimeter. I am new to NumPy and I'm struggling on finding an answer anywhere else.

Below is a chunk of my code that is responsible for outputting the array:

```
def choice_2():
    n = int(input("Please enter a positive integer for n: "))
    a1 = 2 * n +1
    a2 = 4 * n
    a = np.array(list(range(a1, a2+1)))
    for j in range(a1, a2+1):
        b = (2 * n * a)/(a - 2 * n)

    print(f"\nIsis rectangles of type {n}")
    print("----------------------------")
    print(np.array(list(zip(a,b))))
```

And this is what my output is:

```
Isis rectangles of type 10
----------------------------
[[ 21.         420.        ]
 [ 22.         220.        ]
 [ 23.         153.33333333]
 [ 24.         120.        ]
 [ 25.         100.        ]
 [ 26.          86.66666667]
 [ 27.          77.14285714]
 [ 28.          70.        ]
 [ 29.          64.44444444]
 [ 30.          60.        ]
 [ 31.          56.36363636]
 [ 32.          53.33333333]
 [ 33.          50.76923077]
 [ 34.          48.57142857]
 [ 35.          46.66666667]
 [ 36.          45.        ]
 [ 37.          43.52941176]
 [ 38.          42.22222222]
 [ 39.          41.05263158]
 [ 40.          40.        ]]
```

The math is working properly and it is zipping correctly, but I want to remove the rectangles that have float values. For example, the first rectangle with sides 21 and 420 is good, but the thrid rectangle with sides 23 and 153.33333333 is not something I want in the final array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the indices which has integer values and filter `a` and `b` using this indices

```
idx = (b == b.astype(int)).nonzero()
print(np.array(list(zip(a[idx],b[idx]))))
```

Testcase:

```
n= 10
a1 = 2 * n +1
a2 = 4 * n
a = np.array(list(range(a1, a2+1)))
for j in range(a1, a2+1):
    b = (2 * n * a)/(a - 2 * n)

print(f"\nIsis rectangles of type {n}")
print("----------------------------")
idx = (b == b.astype(int)).nonzero()
print(np.array(list(zip(a[idx],b[idx]))))
```

Output:

```
Isis rectangles of type 10
----------------------------
[[ 21. 420.]
 [ 22. 220.]
 [ 24. 120.]
 [ 25. 100.]
 [ 28.  70.]
 [ 30.  60.]
 [ 36.  45.]
 [ 40.  40.]]
```